# c# Call child method from parent method

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

```
public class ClassParrent
{    
        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CurrentActionKey == ActionKeys.Enum.create)
                    Page_Load_create(sender,e);
            if (CurrentActionKey == ActionKeys.Enum.update)
                    Page_Load_update(sender, e);
        }    
        public virtual void Page_Load_create(object sender, EventArgs e){}
        public virtual void Page_Load_update(object sender, EventArgs e){}
}

public class ClassChild : ClassParrent
{
        public override void Page_Load_create(object sender, EventArgs e){}
        public override void Page_Load_update(object sender, EventArgs e){}
}
```

Is there any way that, when Page_Load is called from the ClassParrent, override method in ClassChild will be called?

test Answers from [Call child method from parent c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926078/call-child-method-from-parent-c-sharp) but not work.

Comment: You could give the functions the 'abstract' keyword, however that would only work if you do not plan to write code for those functions in the ClassParrent.

Comment: What does not work from attached question?

Comment: i don't use 'abstract' because it has many child Class, and most classes do not need the implementation of abstract methods

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski : not work, virtual method called

Comment: In actually the child classes it is web forms

Comment: If the instance is of type `ClassChild` then the override will be used, but if the instance is of type `ClassParrent` then the virtual method will be used. How are you creating your instance?

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay : In actually the child class is web form and asp.net create instance of `ClassChild`

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay: thanks so much, i fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ClassParrent
{    
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            if (CurrentActionKey == ActionKeys.Enum.create)
                    Page_Load_create(e);
            if (CurrentActionKey == ActionKeys.Enum.update)
                    Page_Load_update( e);
        }    
        public virtual void Page_Load_create(EventArgs e){}
        public virtual void Page_Load_update(EventArgs e){}
}

public class ClassChild : ClassParrent
{
        public override void Page_Load_create(EventArgs e){}
        public override void Page_Load_update(EventArgs e){}
}
```

fix it :)